# Add the camera on current position of the user on the map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swift4

I added this code in my viewController

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import GoogleMaps

class CourseClass2: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UINavigationControllerDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView!

}
```

and this extension

```
extension CourseClass2:  CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    func determineMyCurrentLocation() {

        guard currentLocation == nil else {
            return
        }

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self 
        locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

        manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        print("user latitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)")
        print("user longitude = \(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)")

        didReceiveUserLocation(userLocation)
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error \(error)")
        errorGettingCurrentLocation(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse || status == .authorizedAlways {
            locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
            //locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
        } else if status == .denied || status == .restricted {
            errorGettingCurrentLocation("Location access denied")
        }
    }

    func errorGettingCurrentLocation(_ errorMessage:String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController.init(title: "Error", message: errorMessage, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

to get the user location. Now i would like to add in the viewDidLoad of my controller a camera like  `let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: , longitude: , zoom: 14)` on the user position, but how can i do to use in this line the latitude and longitude of my user current position that i found with my extension?

Comment: Obviously use variables.

Comment: can you give me an example please i'm a little confused

Comment: Store user location received in a variable . declare a variable var userLocation:CLLocation , and when u receive it in your extension then assign it. and then use it like this : let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude:userLocation.coordinate.latitude , longitude:userLocation.coordinate.longitude , zoom: 14)

Comment: ok but this is my problem, userLocation is a constant in my extension, so if i write userLocation.coordinate in the viewDidLoad of my controller it doesn't read it

Comment: i mean add a variable in your class CourseClass2(i.e. class level variable) It will be vailable for both the class and extension. Also u want to write the camera method in view did load but location delegate takes some time to return current location. So just make a method for camera and call it from delegate method. Or you can use not nill check view did load , but it will never get called on time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` in `viewDidLoad()` where locationManager is CLLocationManager object. As soon as your current location is retrieved, `didUpdateLocations` delegate method is called where you can set the camera position as follows:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let userLocation = locations.last

    let location = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: userLocation!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: userLocation!.coordinate.longitude, zoom: 16.0)

    mapView.animate(to: location)

}
```